# Use internal pull up resistors with the gpio-keys module in the device-tree

Tags: raspbian, gpio, device-tree

I have an external board with some buttons that are attached to gpio 20 and 21 which connects these pins to ground when pressed:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fowYID.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'd like to emit the keys x (fire_left) and o (fire_right) when the buttons are pressed.

I used the following dts file (joystick.dts):

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;
/ {
   compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709", "brcm,bcm2710";

   fragment@0 {
      target-path = <&gpio>;
      __overlay__ {

         butt_pins: butt_pins {
             brcm,pins = <20 21>;    // gpio no.
             brcm,function = <0 0>;  // 0:in, 1:out
             brcm,pull = <2 2>;      // 2:up 1:down 0:none
         };
      };
   };

   fragment@1 {
      target-path = "/";
      __overlay__ {
         pinctrl-names = "default";
         pinctrl-0 = <&butt_pins>;

         keypad: joystick {
            compatible = "gpio-keys";
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            autorepeat;
            button@21 {
               label = "fire_right";
               linux,code = <24>;  // o
               gpios = <&gpio 21 1>;
            };

            button@20 {
               label = "fire_left";
               linux,code = <45>;  // x
               gpios = <&gpio 20 1>;
            };
         };
      };
   };
};
```

I compiled it with:

```
 dtc -Idts -O dtb -o joystick.dtbo joystick.dts -W no-unit_address_vs_reg
```

and used the following command to load it:

```
sudo dtoverlay joystick.dtbo
```

My problem is, that, although I configured in `fragment@0` pullups for the gpios, the Raspberry pi ignored this setting and doesn't set the pullups.

The output of `sudo grep gpio /sys/kernel/debug/gpio` (buttons are not pressed!):

```
gpiochip0: GPIOs 0-53, parent: platform/3f200000.gpio, pinctrl-bcm2835:
 gpio-20  (                    |fire_left           ) in  lo
 gpio-21  (                    |fire_right          ) in  lo
gpiochip2: GPIOs 100-101, brcmvirt-gpio, can sleep:
 gpio-100 (                    |?                   ) out hi
gpiochip1: GPIOs 128-135, brcmexp-gpio, can sleep:
 gpio-135 (                    |?                   ) in  hi
```

As you can see, gpio-20 and gpio-21 got the correct lable and are set as input. Unfortunately the input value is low and not hight as it would be expected if the pullups where set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

In `fragment@0` you have to use `target=<&gpio>;` instead of `target-path = <&gpio>`.